# Is there a way to pass parameters/variables in an XPath statement in .NET?

Tags: c#, xpath, parameter-passing

Is there a way in the C# XPath to pass a parameter like you can do with a SQL select? For example:

```
XPathExpression expr = nav.Compile("/root/employee[@name = @p1]");
expr.SetParameter ("@p1", "Smith");
```

Where it would then handle all escapes, placing quotes around it, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .net XPath support is for XPath 1.0. However, there is an easy way to add support for variables where you can do the equivilent of a SetParameter() call on a SQL select call. This also gives you support for defining your own functions, like matches(). (This is from my blog - [Windward Wrocks](http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2011/07/adding-xpath-20-functionality-and-variables-to-net-xpath.html).)

Note: I was not able to find a way to add support for inequalities on dates. If anyone knows of a way to add this, please let me know.

You need to create a custom XsltContext. Two good references for this are [Case-insensitive XPath in .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shjin/archive/2005/07/22/442025.aspx) and [Adding Custom Functions to XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950806.aspx).

The code in [XPathCustomContext.cs](http://blogs.windwardreports.com/files/xpathcustomcontext.cs) is well documented and straightforward so I'm not going to write about it here. However a couple of notes when using it:

1. Change the Prefix and Namespace values so you're not walking on our
   namespace.
2. You put a variable in the XPath as $name. You pass it in
   XsltArgumentList and have it passed to you in ResolveVariable as
   name (no $).

And here's the biggie – you must call all Evaluate() and Select*() calls using XpathExpressions as shown below. If you use the call where you directly pass in the XPath as a string you will get an exception that says you are using an unknown function. This occurs even if you pass in your custom context.

```
private object SelectSingleNodeTyped(XPathNavigator nav, string select, XsltArgumentList parameters)
{
myContext.ArgList = parameters;
XPathExpression exp = nav.Compile(myXPathSelect);
exp.SetContext(myContext);
object obj = nav.Evaluate(exp);
```